# Would Flash run faster if I ran the Windows version in a VM?

Tags: windows-7, flash, vmware

I know there are several performance issues with Adobe flash player on Ubuntu (any Linux distro).

Has anyone tried to install Windows 7 using VMWare on ubuntu, and then run flash player within the windows 7? Is it possible to get same performance as if you are running flash on a "pure" Windows 7 system?

I want to switch to Ubuntu, but I can't live without flash player.

Thanks.

Note: Would be nice if all the down voters leave a comment to tell me why this is a bad question.

Comment: VMWare will indeed work as much as virtual box. But flash worked correctly without problem most of the time.

Comment: Ofcourse flash player works. But it lags when playing 1080p full screen + takes a lot of resources in Linux compared to windows. I wanted to know if someone has tried running flash in a virtual Windows box and see if you get the same issues. The question is not about which virtual OS solution to use.

Comment: the answer is YES it is working, it just depends of your hardware. Also where is the need of streaming at 1080p O_o but that's my news group background talking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on you to tell what's your meaning with performance . I was working on a company about 2 years ago as AS3 Developer and i installed Adobe Flash Cs6 on VBox with windows 7 on it . We built that project on it without any problem . It depends on your VBox configuration for that windows . however you shouldn't get into problem most of time .

Comment: All I want is to play 1080p video on youtube. Have you tried this on Ubuntu vs. using VBox windows?
On Ubuntu the video lags. I don't have any issue in Windows. It's just that flash player isn't really optimized for Linux.

Comment: yes, it works flawlessly.

Answer (score 2):

Try pipelight. It's running flash, shockwave, silverlight and unity player through wine http://fds-team.de/cms/pipelight-installation.html

Comment: you answer is better than his one